# Executing delete statement with Rowsets

Tags: java, mysql

Hi there I just started programming there 6 months ago and was introduced into RowSets and ResultSets usig the JBDC.

i am jus doing some practice and cant seem to issue a delete SQL statement statement using jdbcRowsetImpl.

```
row.setCommand("delete from student_table where Student_ID=?");
row.setInt(1, 5);
row.execute();
```

i am using try catch nd i am deleting with the primary key which is 5 in this case.

But i keep  getting an error saying that i cant manipulate the data using and execute statement.

I know using ResultsSets that there is an executeupdate that your pose to use that but how can I execuate this statement using Rowssets without moving the cursor to the row i want to delete and issuing the call deleteRow.

Thank in advance
Fionn.

Comment: By the way `jdbcRowsetImpl` is all about results sets not updating,deleting stuff in database. use try catch that will clearly show you the issue.

Comment: Hi susheel, I am using try catches as project wont compile properly, I get the error that 'i cant use data manipulating language using the execute statement. when im using RowSets

Comment: do u suggest that i make a method to convert to resultsets

Comment: `jdbcRowsetImpl` this is deprecated, so using this is not reliable for future. and without using resultset and cursor moving, rows cannot be deleted by using `jdbcRowsetImpl`. 
    `stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);`